# Uniqueness Theorem for integrable functions over a filtered probality spaces

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\{\mathcal{F}_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}},\mu)$ be a filtered probability space and $f$ and $g$ be two integrable functions, such that for all $A\in\mathcal{F}_n$

$\int_Afd\mu=\int_Ag d\mu  -(*)$

Show that $f=g$ $a.e.$ on $\mathcal{F}$

I thought that this would be quite straightforward but am a bit stuck so any help will be greatly appreciated. My initial thoughts were to use the typical procedure and show that $\mathcal{A}:=\{A\in\mathcal{F} | (*) \text{holds}\}$ is equal to $\mathcal{F}$, but am stuck trying to show $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under complements and countable unions. I attempted to use the measurable set $\{\omega|f\geq g\}$ to help out which is standard in these types of questions and didnt get anywhere. So would really appreciate any help whether it is fixing my method or if this is wrong or there is a simpler strategy please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is $\mathcal F$ related to the sub-$\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal F_n$?. Should the assumption be true for any $n$? In this case, the best you can get is that $\mathbb E\left[f\mid \mathcal G\right]  =\mathbb E\left[g\mid \mathcal G\right]$ where $\mathcal G$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $\mathcal F_n$.

Comment: Sorry $\mathcal{F}=\sigma\{\mathcal{F}_n|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, so how do I get your equation? Thanks.

Comment: And $\mathcal{F}_n\subset\mathcal{F}_{n+1}$ and $(*)$ holds for every $n$

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you do not assume $f,g \in L^1$, then the conclusion is not true in general.

Indeed it is not hard to construct a strictly positive  measurable function $f$  on $[0,1]$ which is finite everywhere yet its integral WRT Lebesge measure on any open interval is infinite. If ${\cal F}_n$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $[0,2^{-n}),[2^{-n},2*2^{-n}),\dots,[(2^n-1)2^{-n},1]$, then ${\cal F}$ is the Borel-$\sigma$ algerba. Letting  $g=2f$, then the condition is satisfied yet, $g>f$ a.s. ($f$ was strictly positive).

Therefore we'll assume $f,g \in L^1(P)$.

To prove, you can use a monotone class argument. Let ${\cal M}=\{A \in {\cal F}: \int_A f  dP = \int_A g dP\}$. Then:

1. By monotone convergence and fact that $f$ and $g$ in $L^1$, we have that ${\cal M}$ is a monotone class. That is if $(A_j:j=1,\dots)$ is an increasing, resp. decreasing, sequence of elements in ${\cal M}$ then their union, resp. intersection, is in ${\cal M}$. Note: we only needed the integrability to show that intersection of decreasing seqeucnes is in ${\cal M}$.
2. ${\cal M}$ contains the algebra ${\cal A}= \cup_{n=1}^\infty {\cal F}_n$ (algebra is a nonempty collection of sets closed under (finite) unions and complement).

By [Dynkin's Monotone Class Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem), ${\cal M}$ contains the $\sigma$-algebra generated by ${\cal A}$, ${\cal F}$. That is ${\cal M} \supseteq {\cal F}$.

As a result, $\int _A f dP  = \int_A gdP$. for all $A\in {\cal F}$, in particular on the set $A=\{f>g\}$. Therefore, $f\le g$ a.s. Repeating the argument shows that $g\le f$, hence $f=g$ a.s.

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot, but I am still unsure how you show that $\mathcal{M}$ is a monotone class, as all we know is that $f,g\in L^1$ and are not necessarily non-negative (or non-positive), so how can we infer that $A_i\subset A_j$ $\Rightarrow$ $\int_{A_i}fdP\leq\int_{A_j}fdP$. I would really appecite it if you can claer this up for me, thanks again

Comment: To show that ${\cal M}$ is a monotone class (this has nothing with monotonicity of positivity of integrals you mentioned), you need to show that if $A_1\subseteq A_2 \dots $, are all elements in ${\cal M}$, then $\cup A_j \in {\cal M}$, and that if $B_1\subseteq B_2 \subseteq \dots $ are all elements in ${\cal M}$, then $\cap B_j \in {\cal  M}$. In the case of the problem in question,   both are obtained as straightforward applications of dominated convergence. Hope this clarifies the point.

Comment: Ok, I got a bit confused and tried to use Monotone convergence theorem,. So just to clarify this, for an increasing sequence of sets $\{A_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ we have $fI_{A_i}\rightarrow fI_{\bigcup_i A_i}$ and as $|fI_{A_i}|\leq |f|$, while also noting that everything is in $L^1$ we can apply DCT, which gives $fI_{\bigcup_i A_i}\in L^1$. Then similarly with we get $gI_{\bigcup_i A_i}\in L^1$ and so $\int fI_{\bigcup_i A_i} dP= \int gI_{\bigcup_i A_i} dP$, by uniqueness of limits. Is my reasoning now correct? Thank you again for all the help

Comment: Yep. That's correct.